# Creating a table in MySQL with PHP

Tags: mysql, primary-key, create-table

I am learning PHP and MySQL, i want to create a table in MySQL with PHP but I got this error messager:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' FirstName VARCHAR(20), SecondName VARCHAR(20))' at line 1

My code :

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "alpha0";

    $dbConnected = new mysqli($hostname, $name, $password, $dbName);

    $command = "CREATE TABLE people(ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY, 
                                    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
                                    SecondName VARCHAR(20))";

    if ($dbConnected->query($command))
        echo "True";
    else
        echo mysqli_error($dbConnected);

    mysqli_close($dbConnected);
?>
```

Comment: echo $command and review mysql CREATE TABLE syntax?

Comment: if you show us the whole SQL statement we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a PHP issue, your SQL is incorrect. The `PRIMARY` should be `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE people(ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
                    SecondName VARCHAR(20)
                   )
```